# Firebase Security Rules Access newData Node Name

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I couldn't find any way to access the name of the data that is being written in Firebase Rules, which is very critical for me. 
Does Firebase Rules supports such thing?

```
"tests":{
    "$test":{

      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
     ".write": "auth.uid  != null
         "$user_id":{".validate": "newData.isBoolean() && auth.uid == NewData.NAME(?)"}

    }
  }
```

***Sample data that is gonna be written:***

```
{
  "YHer1txgZyReM8dEkSCTDg4l2ro1": true
}
```

***Sample database structure:***

```
"tests":{
    "test1":{

       "YHer1txgZyReM8dEkSCTDg4l2ro1": true,
       "A4sfgYhred1festfsefsSRGFsgr3": true,
       "7JIsfgYhred1festfsefsSRGFsg8": true,

    }
 "test2":{

      "YHer1txgZyReM8dEkSCTDg4l2ro1": true,
      "A4sfgYhred1festfsefsSRGFsgr3": true,
      "7JIsfgYhred1festfsefsSRGFsg8": true,

    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of the security rules where you're trying to use this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've written a quick sample. The idea behind of it is I don't want users to create any other node different than their user id under this public $test node.

Comment: Instead of `newData.NAME(?)` use `$test`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But it's for the node under of it. Also the $test node must be creatable by anyone who is authenticated. Probably I should use validate for it. I've added a sample database structure for better understanding.  Could you please check Mr. Puffelen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `newData.NAME(?)` use `$user_id`.

So:

```
 "tests":{
    "$test":{

      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
     ".write": "auth.uid  != null
         "$user_id":{".validate": "newData.isBoolean() && auth.uid == $user_id"}"

    }
  }
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable), which contains an example that is very close to what you need.

Comment: The edited version of the answer allows users with different userid to delete the data because validate doesn't check for delete operations. Is there any way to prevent this?